# RMI "interface implementing remote"

Tags: java

Trying out RMI in eclipse. I created 2 packages named Server and Client

I created the interface extending "Remote" in the Server package. Copied this file to the Client side

But, after doing so, When I ran the client side code, it gave a error saying "ClassCastException" cannot convert proxy01 to .........

But, when I complied the interface file within Server package and copied the .class file  of the interface in the client's bin folder, it started out to work

Why does the .class file of the interface need to be the same? (of the remote interface in the client and the server package)

Comment: Well, because just copying the class definition does not mean both are the same class. Have you tried `import`ing the `Server.proxy01` class into your classes of the `Client` package? (Java uses fully qualified, non-colliding names for your classes. You were trying to convert `Client.proxy01` to `Server.proxy01`; the package name may have been taken from the directory structure)

Comment: thanks, shall try this out and post a update